# I didn't get correct time when using time formatter

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When i tried to get date and time from two textfields, i got incorrect time. 
my input

```
date.text = may 20 2000    
time.text = 02:00 AM

but i got the time in nslog is :00:00:00 





NSString *datestring = self.date.text;
NSString *timestring = self.time.text;
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", datestring, timestring];
NSLog(@"%@",combined);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dates = [dateFormat dateFromString:combined];
self.create.hidden = YES;
NSLog(@"%@",dates);
```

any help 
please?

Answer (score 0):

You have `time.text = 02:00 AM` and you set your formatter on `HH:mm:ss`.

It's a wrong formatter, that's why is null.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong formatter, it must be:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa"];
```