# Getting wrong time from NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate

When I try to get values for date and time from text fields I got wrong value on console. Date and time are two text fields

```
NSString *datestring = self.date.text;
NSString *timestring = self.time.text;
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",datestring,timestring];
NSLog(@"%@",combined);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dates = [dateFormat dateFromString:combined];

NSLog(@"%@",dates);
```

Comment: what is the output of `combined` string object ?

Comment: Can you post the input/output values and what is the expected output?

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891266/i-didnt-get-correct-time-when-using-time-formatter

Comment: you should set time zone to `defaultTimeZone`.

Comment: date: may 2 2000   time: 02:00 AM
output of  combined: may 2 2000 02:00 AM
output of  dates : 2000-05-01 18:30:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on the `NSDate` `description` method to give you the date you want, it is really just for debugging. Instead use `NSDateFormatter` method `stringFromDate:`.

```
NSString *combinedDateString = @"may 2 2000 02:00 AM";
NSLog(@"combinedDateString: %@", combinedDateString);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:combinedDateString];

NSString *recoveredDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"recoveredDateString: %@", recoveredDateString);
```

NSLog output:

> combinedDateString:  may 2 2000 02:00 AM
>   recoveredDateString: May 02 2000 02:00 AM

Choose a different display format as desired.

Note: "HH" is for 24 hour time, "hh" is for 12 hour time.

See [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) for date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong formatter, it must be:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa"];
```

You have already open a subject:
[I didn't get correct time when using time formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891266/i-didnt-get-correct-time-when-using-time-formatter)

Comment: still having the same issue combined: may 22 2000 02:00 AM
 dates:2000-05-21 20:30:00 +0000